# Connecting two nodes in I2P with SSH

Tags: ssh

I have 2 clients, both of them running I2P. Is it possible to connect them through SSH within the I2P network?

For example: Client 2 setup SSH server and Client 1 connects to it. All this happens while they both connected to I2P.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible.

On Client 2:

- Create a `Standard server` tunnel in I2PTunnel.
- Set the `Name` to something you will recognize.
- Set the `Target Port` to the port your SSH server is listening on.
- Check the `Auto Start` box.
- Save the tunnel.
- Open the tunnel for editing again (click on its name in the I2PTunnel list).
- Copy the `Local destination` string.

On Client 1:

- Create a `Standard client` tunnel in I2PTunnel.
- Set the `Name` to something you will recognize.
- Paste the `Local destination` string you copied earlier into the `Tunnel Destination` field.
- Set the `Access Point Port` to some free port (e.g. `12345`).
- (Optionally) check the `Auto Start` box.
- Save the tunnel.

When both tunnels are running, connecting to Client 2 from Client 1 is as simple as:

`ssh username@127.0.0.1 -p 12345`

For some additional security, you can add whitelisting to the server tunnel. This means that only someone with the private keys to your client tunnel can connect to the server Destination.

On Client 1:

- Open the client tunnel for editing.
- Under `Persistent private key`, select `Enable`, and change the name in `File` to something you will recognize.

  - This file is stored in your I2P config directory (on *nix systems, this will be ~/.i2p/). If this file is lost or deleted, a new different set of keys will be generated when the Client 1 router restarts, and you will not be able to SSH into Client 2 until you add the new keys to the whitelist.
- Save the tunnel and restart it.
- Open the tunnel for editing again, and copy the `Local destination` string.

On Client 2:

- Open the server tunnel for editing.
- Under `Restricted Access List(s)`, select `Whitelist`.
- Paste the `Local destination` string you copied earlier into the `Access List` box.
- Save the tunnel and restart it.

Comment: Adding an important bit to str4d's answer. On both Client 1 and Client 2 tunnels you should set `Profile` to `interactive connection`. Also, on Client 1 check `Delay Connect`. Source: killyourtv answer on [I2P bug #746 (ssh over i2p?)](https://trac.i2p2.de/ticket/746).

Comment: I'm trying the whitelist part, but my ssh client report `connection closed by remote host` after enabling it. How could I solve the problem? I'm sure I keyed in the correct `Local Destination` string.